# Send a parameter along with sendfile

Tags: node.js

I am using nodejs

i have this code

```
var someparameter ="teststst";
var fileLocation = path.resolve(__dirname + '/../public/resetpassword.html');
            console.log(fileLocation);
            res.sendfile(fileLocation);
```

I want to send **someparameter**  in resetpassword.html 
Can anybody tell me how to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't. (not without an engine)

Passing parameters to the html won't have any effect (and isnt possible)
You can use a template engine such as jade (or EJS if you want to stay with HTML)

Defined as:

```
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

And than you can 'render' view with parameters:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {
    users: users,
    title: "EJS example",
    header: "Some users"
  });
});
```

Usaful Info:

1. [EJS templates](http://www.embeddedjs.com/)
2. [Use EJS to Template Your Node Application](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application)